# SQL grouping on a field does not work

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have an issue with the sql line written down below. Most of it is done with the designer of Access and I changed a couple of things like the joins. The joins work, but it does not seem to want to group the week which is a field of tbl1 in this example.

Can anyone see what I am missing here and point out an answer?

```
SELECT tbl2.[name], 
       tbl1.[week], 
       tbl1.[production], 
       Sum(tbl3.[sales]) AS total sales, 
       (tbl1.[production]/tbl3.[sales]) AS Conversion
  FROM (tbl1 RIGHT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.[ID] = tbl2.[ID]) 
        RIGHT JOIN tbl3 ON tbl2.[ID] = tbl3.[ID]
  GROUP 
     BY tbl2.[name], 
        tbl1.[week], 
        tbl1.[production], 
        (tbl1.[production]/tbl3.[sales])
 HAVING (((tbl1.[week]) Between [Start week] And [end Week]))
 ORDER BY tbl1.[week];
```

Comment: "does not seem to want to group the week". Are you getting an error or unexpected output? What's your input and expected output? I'm guessing you are grouping by an additional unrequired column making the week look like it is repeating. You'll need to identify that column then either aggregate it or exclude it altogether.

Comment: so the problem I experience with this is that it sums up the sales and totals that in all weeks. In an query where I select 4 weeks it shows me a 166 rows, where I would only want 4 rows for the 4 selected weeks.

Comment: No need for HAVING (((tbl1.[week]) Between [Start week] And [end Week])). The correct way is WHERE tbl1.[week]<Between [Start week] And [end Week]

Comment: So take out the columns that cause the extra rows to appear. If you just want a summary by weeks, only include weeks in your group by.  i.e. remove name and production.

Comment: ahh Alexandros actually solved the issues. When I used Where instead of Having it did sum them up when I grouped them together. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

from what i know is when you do a group by you do it with the very same fields you selected. so, in your case try this:

```
SELECT tbl2.[name], tbl1.[week], tbl1.[production], Sum(tbl3.[sales]) AS total sales, (tbl1.[production]/tbl3.[sales]) AS Conversion
FROM (tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.[ID] = tbl2.[ID]) JOIN tbl3 ON tbl2.[ID] = tbl3.[ID]
GROUP BY tbl2.[name], tbl1.[week], tbl1.[production], Sum(tbl3.[sales]), (tbl1.[production]/tbl3.[sales])
HAVING (((tbl1.[week]) Between [Start week] And [end Week]))
ORDER BY tbl1.[week];
```

hope it works, i work with sql server s it might be a little different.

Comment: When I try to do that Access tells me I am not allowed to aggregate a sum in a group by function. I did try to group on the label Conversion before posting, but that gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks reasonable except for:

```
HAVING (((tbl1.[week]) Between [Start week] And [end Week]))
```

`[Start week]` and `[end Week]` either need to be aggregated, in the `group by` clause, or aggregated.  I'm not sure which is the solution you really need.  Here is the first method:

```
HAVING tbl1.[week] Between MIN([Start week]) And MAX([end Week])
```